# Sharing code between commands and toolbar buttons

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm working on a macOS app that shows a list of items. A user can perform different actions on each item using either the toolbar or the main menu. Since they are are just different ways to perform the same actions, I want to re-use the code. What would be a good approach to accomplish it?

Here's an example to illustrate the problem:

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ItemListView()
        }
        .commands {
            ItemCommands()
        }
    }
}

struct ItemListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ...
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItemGroup {
                Button("Button1", action: action1)
                Button("Button2", action: action2)
                Button("Button3", action: action3)
            }
        }
    }

    // Intent functions

    func action1() { ... }
    func action2() { ... }
    func action3() { ... }
}

struct ItemCommands: Commands {
    var body: some Commands {
        CommandMenu("Item") {
            // I want to re-use my intent functions here.
            Button("Button1") { ... }
            Button("Button2") { ... }
            Button("Button3") { ... }
        }
    }
}
```

Up until this point I didn't need to have any view models in my project, but this seems like a good use case for it. I could move my intent functions to a view model and then pass it to `MyItemListView` and `MyItemCommands`.

It's also possible to pass an intent function from a view to a command as a focused value:

```swift
// View
someView.focusedValue(\.myAction1Func, myAction1Func)


// Commands
@FocusedValue(\.myAction1Func) private var myAction1Func

Button("Action1") { myAction1Func?() }
```

But this approach doesn't scale well when you need to pass many different values to implement a command.

Comment: Asking for a “… good approach to accomplish it” is a bit vague in my opinion and I also believe that finding the best solution very much depends on what data the functions depends upon which we don’t know.

Comment: If actions are to be executed at app level, then  define them in App and pass then to the 2 views as parameters. But you can also define a model with the actions in it.

Comment: @PtitXav Thanks! But some actions depend on scene-specific state, so I can't define them at the app level.

Comment: So how do you except actio  declared called in App to execute code depending on scène state ? You need to use a model owned by App then holds the Scene state and the execution of the actions.

Comment: Can you add code to your sample where you access this "scene state"? I would just create a `MenuButtonsViewModel` that executed the logic (it might even return a `some View` with all the buttons as a tupled view) and pass in all the scene/context specific data to either that function (so it's available in the scope) or pass the context individually within the enclosing view scope (i.e. in your example it's `CommandMenu() { Button("1") { vm.action1(sceneSpecificState) }}`

Answer (score 0):

use ViewModel:

```
class ItemListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    func action1() { ... }
    func action2() { ... }
    func action3() { ... }
}
```

In your main app structure and views, you'd do something like:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ItemListViewModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ItemListView(viewModel: viewModel)
        }
        .commands {
            ItemCommands(viewModel: viewModel)
        }
    }
}

struct ItemListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ItemListViewModel

    var body: some View {
        
        Button("Button1", action: viewModel.action1)
    }
}

struct ItemCommands: Commands {
    var viewModel: ItemListViewModel

    var body: some Commands {
        CommandMenu("Item") {
            Button("Button1", action: viewModel.action1)
            Button("Button2", action: viewModel.action2)
            Button("Button3", action: viewModel.action3)

        }
    }
}
```